# Social Login First but wants to add password login

Tags: auth0

We support 2 types of Auth0 logins at our customized login page:

1. Google login
2. Email/Password signup/login

A user started with a Google login but wants to add a password login to his account. What can we do? I tried the reset password link on the universal login, but it didn’t send the reset password email. Please advise!

Comment: The problem involves a solution which has nothing to do with google OAuth2. What didn't send the reset password? When your user wants to upgrade to email/password type account and you have their email from Google, you have to "sendmail" through your server side script as technically google will not be involved in the account after the account upgrade. Their gmail address is just "any old email address" and you will have to store the logins and passwords on your own server. You cite the problem is them not receiving the reset password email. This is an issue with sendmail or junkmail. More info

Comment: Yes, it is related to Auth0 not sending a reset password issues. I'm asking why Auth0 is not sending reset password emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make sure Google auth users always create an email-password account for them and link them together

1. When a Google Auth user signs up,

   - Use [management API](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/post_users) to create an email-password account with the same email address
   - Use a randomly generated password to prevent security risk
   - Set "email_verified": true (because this email is Google-authenticated already)
2. Now link this Google user account with this newly generated email-password user together by the [management API](https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/user-accounts/user-account-linking/suggested-account-linking-server-side-implementation#metadata-merge-example)